# XSL transform to new Window (problems in IE 10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xslt

This for an non-profit, non-denominational site, tanach.us.

I'm trying to XSL transform text into a new window.  What I have works in Firefox, even on Windows.

```
var newWindow = window.open() ;
var doc = newWindow.document ;

setTemplateToNode(tanachIndexXML, tanachXSL, "Unicode", doc.all[0] ) ;
```

where doc.all[0] is the top node in the new document of the new window.  The output
of the XSL transformation is a full HTML document starting with an  tag.

I do get mysterious warnings in Firefox, but the operation is correct.  On IE 10, a blank page appears.

Comment: Well how does `setTemplateToNode` exactly look? XSLT, Javascript and DOM interaction is very different in Firefox and IE so code working with Firefox does not necessarily work with IE. Does the sample you have work with earlier IE versions? Where do you get the XSLT and XML input documents from? IE 10 is know to return `responseXML` of `XMLHttpRequest` as IE DOM documents (and not MSXML DOM documents) so that could be one reason why XSLT works different. But the error console should show some error.